# Swift Compiler Error - Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: swift

I'm trying to follow the swift tutorial on Youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BZdQmHV4MQ&t=471s

But I'm getting this warning sign and I have no idea how I could solve it.

This is my code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoItem.getAllToDoItems()) var toDoItems:FetchedResults<ToDoItem>

@State private var newTodoItem = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List{
            Section(header: Text("What's next?")){
                HStack{
                    TextField("New item", text: self.$newTodoItem)
                    Button(action: {
                        let toDoItem = ToDoItem(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                        toDoItem.title = self.newTodoItem
                        toDoItem.createdAt = Date()
                        
                        do {
                            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        }catch{
                            print(error)
                        }
                        
                        self.newTodoItem = ""
                        
                    }){
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                    }
                }
            }.font(.headline)
            Section(header: Text("To Do's")) {
                ForEach(self.toDoItems) {todoItem in
                    ToDoItemView(title: todoItem.title!, createdAt: "\(todoItem.createdAt!)")
                }.onDelete {IndexSet in
                    let deleteItem = self.toDoItems[IndexSet.first!]
                    self.managedObjectContext.delete(deleteItem)
                    
                    do{
                        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                    }catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                
                }
                
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("My List"))
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

And I get the error at this part

```
                        ToDoItemView(title: todoItem.title!, createdAt: "\(todoItem.createdAt!)")
```

And ToDoItemView code is this.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ToDoItemView: View {
var body: some View {
    Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
}
}

struct ToDoItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ToDoItemView()
    }
}
```

It says that it's 'Swift Compiler Error - Argument passed to call that takes no arguments'.

What should I do?

Comment: Show the code for `ToDoItemView`. Also while asking on SO keep in mind to ask by providing [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks, it's my first time to ask here. and the `ToDoItemView` is this.

Comment: I meant to add the code to your question, not in the comments.

Comment: @Frankenstein Oh Sorry, I added it to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now `ToDoItemView` doesn't have any properties that needs to be initialized when declaring `ToDoItemView`. So, to avoid the error while building you can use the empty initializer for now. As you move forward with the tutorial add the initializer which initializes `title` and `createdAt`. So, for now you can use the empty initializer, instead of:

```
ToDoItemView(title: todoItem.title!, createdAt: "\(todoItem.createdAt!)")
```

Use:

```
ToDoItemView()
```